# Padding reduzindo a imagem

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Tenho uma imagem com um fundo trabalhado, nesta imagem estou dando padding igual 140px, porém em vez da imagem aumentar o padding, e consequentemente, ficar um box maior, a imagem está reduzindo, aumentando o padding para dentro da imagem mantendo a proporção da imagem?

O problema começou quando eu migrei o conteúdo para um container de outra página que utiliza bootstrap. Alguém faz ideia do que pode estar havendo neste CSS?

Esta é a versão do [padding antigo (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/zgxb6aox/):

```
img.image.resize { }
```

> Se aumentar de 140px para 300px por exemplo ele aumenta tudo (mas no novo que estou fazendo ele não faz isso...

Veja na imagem, o que acontece quando tiro o padding:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Inclua o código em sua pergunta, utilizando o snippet

Comment: o problema é que é muito código.

Comment: Cara, pra que serve "matrix(0.190268, 0, 0, 0.190268, 4, -35)"? Tenta tirar isso pra ver se te ajuda. Tira o padding e trabalha com altura e largura fixa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o Bootstrap tem por padrão todos os elementos com `box-sizing border-box`. Com isso, o tamanho da imagem se ajusta em relação às suas bordas, e não ao seu conteúdo.

Para resolver isso é preciso alterar o `box-sizing` para `content-box`. Basta adicionar na classe mencionada na pergunta:

```
img.image.resize {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Se quiser aplicar a todos os elementos da página o [valor padrão](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) do estilo:

```
* {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: valeu, na mosca!